# jQuery and html 5 <template> tag

Tags: jquery, templates, html5-template

I have some problem with jQuery.
When am trying use:

```
document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(content.cloneNode(true));
```

it's ok, but jquery have wrapper around the object, so i can't just type:

```
$('#container').content
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the actual DOM element for a single-element selection, use `$('#container')[0]` or `$('#container').get(0)`.

If you had multiple elements in your selection, you could get them by index: `.get(1)`, `.get(2)` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The HTML5 provides a `template` element:

```
contents = $('#template').html();
copy = $('<div id="copy"></div>');
$('body').append(copy.append(contents));
```

The HTML part:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <template id='template'>
    </template>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `clone` method is not sufficient.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading. You are not importing the template, you are re-parsing the template's html.

Comment: @chowey How would you `import` the template?

Comment: @BananaAcid something like this: `$('#container').append($('#template')[0].content.cloneNode(true))` (see answer from @nrabinowitz)